# SCons in Python

Tags: python, scons

I would like to load SCons in an interactive Python session and enter directives that way as opposed to through an SConstruct or SConscript file. Is this possible? I'm trying to embed SCons functionality into another Python application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear so,

> Just add Scons to your PYTHONPATH and
>   import whatever you need. Copy the
>   appropriate bits out of scons' main
>   that suit you - Scons/Script/Main.py -
>   or just run its main from the
>   appropriate folder.

http://osdir.com/ml/programming.tools.scons.user/2005-03/msg00058.html

Comment: Thanks - it was a PEBKAC error. I had tried something like that, but I included SCons in the path itself, i.e. /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/scons-2.0.1/SCons   When I deleted '/SCons' from the end it worked.